# there is a way to host 1 website in 2 Dedicated Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, dedicated-server

I want to host my website `exemple.com` in 2 dedicated servers

i m hosting the website now in one server , connected to the domain  using the nameservers

Now i need to add the second server , how to do it ?

THanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider putting a reverse proxy or loadbalancer in front which points to both webservers.

It's not recommended to loadbalance by just adding two A records pointing to your websites.